# How can i get ascii code for shift+insert

Tags: pascalscript, fastreport

guys! I need help. I have a task where I should locked insert a text by 
shift+insert keys. I develop print form in FastReport using PascalScript language. How can I get ascii code for shift+insert keys ? I have been googled this question during 2 days but I haven't find answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to catch Shift+Insert keys when you press them on a generated report? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right.